# Comparing means of two experiments over time using LME

Tags: lme4-nlme, independence

I have conducted a lab study on ocean warming and corals using an aquaria tower with **3 levels á 4 aquaria**.

Each level depicted one temperature treatment (2 heat treatments and 1 control): Level 1 = temperature 1, level 2 = temperature 2, level 3 = control.

The first round of this experiment was complemented by a second round with a different randomization by level (level 1 = control, level 2 = temperature 1, level 3 = temperature 2).

I took the mean from 3 randomly chosen corals of each aquaria, so 4 observations per treatment and time point.
Each round of the experiment took 25 days to test the effect of increased temperatures over time.

I now want to use LMEs with **day and temperature as fixed effects** and **aquaria as random effect** to find the effect of temperature on ecophysiological parameters.
Which tests can I use to compare both rounds of the experiments, since subjects within rounds are not independent (but I used different corals for each round) and I observe parameters over time?

Thanks a lot in advance!